# (PassportJS) page not route to login page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Thank you in advance for helping!
I am new to using PassportJS and trying to use it to build a user sign up and login feature.
I used the following tutorial and have some questions regarding the step 12.
https://github.com/GM456742/PassportJS_Auth_Tutorial

```
app.post("/api/signup", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    db.User.create({
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    }).then(function() {
      res.redirect(307, "/api/login");
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.json(err);
      // res.status(422).json(err.errors[0].message);
    });
  });
//
```

On that post method for signup, what does it directs users to the member page instead of the login page after the user has signed up? What should be changed if I want it to direct users to the login page after the user has signed up?

I tried changing the redirect from res.redirect(307, "/api/login"); to  res.redirect("login"); and it stays on the sign up page after user has signed up.

Thank you!

Comment: Without reading through that entire tutorial, it's hard to say

Answer (score 0):

It's a redirect post request to `api/login` and returns a json response : `/members` route. You should handle the response from the client and redirect to `/members`.

Comment: Does that mean I would have to modify the get method and not the post method?

Comment: It means your client should detect a redirect. Example, if your using `fetch` set redirect  to `follow` in order to detect the `307` status code.